# Search File Function not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a program for a reddit bot. Part of this program requires me to search a file for a query to prevent double posting here is my code:

```
def search (filetosearch,query):
    with open(filetosearch, 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if len(str(line)) == 0 | query not in line:
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True
                break
```

Whenever I run it, it returns None! Why is is skipping the return statements?
The file I am trying to search is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is empty, then you are never entering your `for` loop, as there is *nothing* for the loop to iterate over.

Just add a `return False` at the end of the function for that edge case.

You also do *not* want to return yet when a line does not match the query, simply loop to the next line instead:

```
def search (filetosearch, query):
    with open(filetosearch, 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if query in line:
                return True

    return False
```

Note that your `break` statements are redundant; the function is exited immediately when a return statement is executed, the next line with the `break` statement is never reached.

Comment: Can i remove the: `if len (str(line))==0 ` stuff now?

Comment: @user76255: I gave you a better implementation (which tests if there is anything in the line minus a newline).

Comment: Why dose it not look in the file?

Comment: @user76255: The file is empty; what do you expect to find?